# How to define a C struct which contain a struct inside a Ctype python

Tags: python, c, ctype

Hi
I am learning python and using ctype to embedd 'C' in python. My query is-
How to use C stru which again calling a stru inside into cytpe/python.

```
typedef struct {    
   struct *i, *j; 
   BOOLEAN z; 
} foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but it looks like you're trying to define a struct that contains a pointer to the same type. It's not immediately obvious how you would accomplish this in python, but you basically define your `Structure`, and then define the `_fields_` attribute afterwards.

The ctype docs on python.org have a perfectly on-point [example](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types) of doing exactly this.

There's also good [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) there on working with structs in general, including nesting one struct type within another, which works a little more obviously.

Comment: Thanks zerocrates. I am going through the mentioned documents. I have got bit understanding of how to define structure in ctype. ok let me redefine my problem-
typedef struct A
 {
 B *x;
 B *y[Z];
 BOOLEAN xx;
 } A;
 Where B is 
typedef struct 
{ 
UINT16 length; 
INT16 offset;
 UINT8 *data; 
UINT8 user_count;
 } B;
And  Z = 10